# iOS camera YUV420 vs GBRA32?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, camera, rgb, yuv

All examples of iOS camera processing that I have seen use camera output in YUV420 format and convert it into RGB in an OpenGL ES 2 shader.

It's not very clear to me, why are everyone doing it, even though you can request camera to return you GBRA32 texture straight away.

I do understand that internal format is in fact YUV420 and it must do a conversion to give out GBRA32, but surely doing conversion manually isn't going to be faster than a letting iOS do it internally?

Is internal conversion implementation really slow or there are other reasons why everyone request YUV420 just to convert it to RGB straight away?

Comment: I guess the reason is bandwidth limitations. In YUV420 format each pixel is 12bits (in average). In GBRA32 each pixel is 32 bits.

Comment: Historically for black and white TV to colour. The U and V planes are half the width and height of the Y plane and each UV byte serves 4 pixels. It's also easy enough to reduce the overhead of converting to RGB or your mentioned format by having the GPU convert the planes on the fly as in a fragment shader. See here for more in depth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV